# Proper File structure in MVC, while making UI programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface

I was wondering how to store in proper way Views, and all elements in iOS Projects, when I'm creating UI programmatically.

I have for ex. RegisterButton function, and this ViewController file.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    view.addSubview(loginRegisterButton)
    setupLoginRegisterButon()     
}


let loginRegisterButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 120, green: 80, blue: 195)
    button.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    return button
}()

func setupLoginRegisterButon() {
    loginRegisterButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    loginRegisterButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContrainerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    loginRegisterButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputsContrainerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    loginRegisterButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
}
```

I should create separate file in "Views", but how to do it in proper, and how to call function that creates all objects in proper way.

Thanks!

Comment: It really is a matter of preference, convenience, and individual/team/company policies. By far, the most important matter is making it build, and maintenance/reusability. I'm guessing you'll receive down votes for this because (1) it's an opinionated question, and (2) it's vague, as in you aren't describing a specific issue.

Comment: Yeah. I know that.. but for the person who starts with little bit more advanced techniques all the opinions that are being said about design patterns are just super confusing. Trying to get any information that just let me be a better Dev ;)